# how to implement conditional tags in javascript

Tags: javascript, servlets

Below is what im trying to attempt.

depends on the http request parameter received, i need to display either success button or failure button.

Able to achieve this in servlet, how to achieve this conditional tags in javascript?

Thanks in advance

Comment: What HTTP request are you talking about? JavaScript has no concept of "tags".

Answer (score 2):

If you have `button = someButton()`

Then later just make an if statement:

```
if (httpRequestParamReceived) {
  button.value = "Success";
} else {
  button.value = "failure";
}
```

Something like this but you should replace needed values as you didn't specify which parameter and which button you want to change.